# Unpivot a table in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I've used a head-on way to unpivot a table but I feel there shoud be more succinct and simple forms. Ideas?

**Input**:

[image]

**Output** (transposed just to save space):

[image]

Long way from input to output:

```
list = {{Null, d, e}, {a, 1, 4}, {b, 2, 3}};

tmp = Thread[Tuples@{#[[2 ;;, 1]], #[[1, 2 ;;]]} -> Flatten@#[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]] & @ list;
Flatten[Table[#, {#2}] & @@@ tmp, {1, 2}] // Transpose // TableForm
```

---

**Addendum**

Just in case: [how to pivot in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099866/how-would-you-do-a-pivottable-function-in-mathematica/43582765#43582765)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `MapIndexed` with `ConstantArray` like this:

```
f[n_, {v_, i_}] := ConstantArray[{list[[v + 1, 1]], list[[1, i + 1]]}, n];
Flatten[MapIndexed[f, list[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], {2}], 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]

f1 = ## & @@@ MapThread[ConstantArray, 
    {Tuples@{#[[2;;, 1]], #[[1, 2;;]]}, ## & @@@ #[[2;;, 2;;]]}] &;

f2 = ## & @@@ ConstantArray @@@ Flatten[{Outer[List, #[[2;;, 1]], #[[1, 2 ;;]]], 
     #[[2;;, 2;;]]}, {{2, 3}, {1}}] &;

f1@list // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f2@list == f1@list
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Corner Null suggests a nested Association approach:

```
ds = <|a -> <|d -> 1, e -> 4|>, b -> <|d -> 2, e -> 3|>|>
```

> <|a -> <|d -> 1, e -> 4|>, b -> <|d -> 2, e -> 3|>|>

Then

```
Dataset[ds] [All, KeyValueMap[Table] /* Flatten][
 KeyMap[List] /* KeyValueMap[List /* Tuples] /* (Flatten[#, 1] &)]
```

> {{a, d}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {b, d}, {b, d}, {b, e}, {b,
>   e}, {b, e}}   (* normal'd *)

Answer (score 2):

With no other constraints or requirements of generality? Then I would write it like this:

```
list = {{Null, d, e}, {a, 1, 4}, {b, 2, 3}};

unpivot[{
   {Null, d_, e_},
   {a_, v1_, v2_},
   {b_, v3_, v4_}
   }] := Join[
  ConstantArray[{a, d}, v1],
  ConstantArray[{a, e}, v2],
  ConstantArray[{b, d}, v3],
  ConstantArray[{b, e}, v4]
  ]

unpivot[list]

(* Out: {{a, d}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {a, e}, {b, d}, {b, d},
 {b, e}, {b, e}, {b, e}} *)
```

It's easy to understand, succinct, and wasn't hard to write down.